# Is there a Boot ROM within other SoCs?

Tags: boot, rom

I was researching on methods to try and recover my data and I learned something interesting, [a user 'kuruczgyurci' posted](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/187502/44325):

> This does not exactly answer the original question, but since I managed to brick my bootloader in the meantime, this is what I ended up doing, and it might be useful for someone else in the future:
>
> Allwinner SOCs have a built in Boot ROM, and it supports various modes, so these devices are virtually unbrickable. In particular, it supports a so called *FEL* mode (http://linux-sunxi.org/FEL) which can be used to boot the device over USB. I nice open-source tool has been written that can communicate with the device in this special mode (http://linux-sunxi.org/Sunxi-tools#sunxi-fel). Using this, you can boot your own bootloader. (And with that, you can boot your own kernel, etc.) The linux-sunxi.org website has very  detailed instructions regarding Allwinner SoC devices, so I recommend that you check out their other articles as well.

I found this quite interesting and so my noggin started to think: could this potentially apply to Snapdragon COCs? Could they potentially contain a built-in Boot ROM?

It would be logically possible considering that if perhaps someone completely ruined important partitions, to the point the boot-loader doesn't even load, and it's completely bricked, that Motorola can fix it.

I'm pretty sure I recall talking to a Moto Rep a long time ago and they said that it is possible to fix a phone that you messed up all the way up to the bootloader.

I would assume 'Yes' they do.
So, is it possible?

Comment: TL;DR that is called Qualcomm HS-USB QDLoader 9008 (EDL) emergency download mode

Comment: @alecxs Thank you for the answer, while this does answer the question, perhaps you have more info on the EDL Mode? I like to learn more about it :)

Comment: check links from this comments [1](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/226838/recovering-data-from-mi-4c-able-to-get-only-to-fastboot#comment296311_226838), [2](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/224131/bootloop-issue-and-cant-go-to-recovery-mode/224235?r=SearchResults#comment305555_224235)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot flash Qualcomm with Stock Image (Lenovo Tab M10 TB-X605L LTE, Android 8 Oreo)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/224369/cannot-flash-qualcomm-with-stock-image-lenovo-tab-m10-tb-x605l-lte-android-8-o)